# Suspect wordpress is not setting cookies

Tags: html, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to make a simple login form.

The wordpress function 
`is_user_logged_in()` always returns false.

I don't want to use any pre-existing themes for wordpress, and I want to simply add wordpress functionality to an existing page.

I checked the cookies on my page with the form, and none are being set.

The wordpress install is located at:
`http://localhost/newgameplus/wordpress/`

The testings script is located at:
`http://localhost/newgameplus/TEST/scripts/php/testWP.php`

EDIT:

Solved this issue by going to wp admin panel, and changing the options. 
Settings>General Settings

Adjusted site Address to reflect the actual website location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is running in a different web space to the WordPress install.  To access the Wordpress functionality you'll need to be working on the site within the wordpress web space - ie the

```
http://localhost/newgameplus/wordpress/
```

directory

Comment: Is there anyway I can get around that?  Or do I do it by 'including' a script in that directory?  And if so, how?